# Why does nothing shows when I set dynamic query in my useQuery?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm struggling to get the data once I set it to dynamic query.

I get the data if I console.log during the `axios` call, but when I tried to call it on using `resultQuery` in my component. I get an empty result.

ApiAction.js

```
export const getUserResult = async (from, end, year, college , type) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/result/query?from=${from}&end=${end}&year=${year}&college=${college}&type=${type}`)
    //const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/result/query?from=8&end=10&year=23&college=COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING AND INFORMATION SCIENCES&type=Students`)
    console.log(response.data)
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors here if needed
    console.log(error)
  }
};
```

This is my useQuery call.

```
export const resultQuery = () => {
    const { isPending, error, data, isFetching, refetch } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['result'], // Update this to match your API call key
        queryFn: getUserResult,
        enabled: false
    })

    return { isPending, data, error, isFetching, refetch }
}
```

Component.js

```
  const {isPending, data: UserResults, error, isFetching, refetch} = resultQuery()

  console.log(UserResults)
const handleClick =  () => {
    // Do something with resultData if needed
    //console.log(data.from, data.end, data.endYear, data.college, data.type)
    getUserResult(data.from, data.end, data.endYear, data.college, data.type)
    refetch()
  };
```

In this image, I get the data through `console.log` in the ApiAction.js, but when I tried to `console.log` on the component, I get an empty `array

[image]